# On Publishing error - is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, user-controls

I have got following `UserControl` that work just fine but when I publish the project I am facing this error.

```
.. is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'
```

How to fix it?

**ASCX**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"      CodeBehind="DataPagerGridView.ascx.cs" Inherits="VerInformes.DataPagerGridView" %>
```

**C#**

```
   public partial class DataPagerGridView : GridView, IPageableItemContainer
    {
        private static readonly object EventTotalRowCountAvailable = new object();

        public int MaximumRows
        {
            get { return this.PageSize; }
        }

        public int StartRowIndex
        {
            get { return this.PageSize * this.PageIndex; }
        }

        public event EventHandler<PageEventArgs> TotalRowCountAvailable
        {
            add { base.Events.AddHandler(DataPagerGridView.EventTotalRowCountAvailable, value); }
            remove { base.Events.RemoveHandler(DataPagerGridView.EventTotalRowCountAvailable, value); }
        }

        public void SetPageProperties(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, bool databind)
        {
            int newPageIndex = (startRowIndex / maximumRows);
            this.PageSize = maximumRows;
            if (this.PageIndex != newPageIndex)
            {
                bool isCanceled = false;
                if (databind)
                {
                    //  create the event arguments and raise the event
                    GridViewPageEventArgs args = new GridViewPageEventArgs(newPageIndex);
                    this.OnPageIndexChanging(args);
                    isCanceled = args.Cancel;
                    newPageIndex = args.NewPageIndex;
                }
                //  if the event wasn't cancelled change the paging values
                if (!isCanceled)
                {
                    this.PageIndex = newPageIndex;
                    if (databind)
                        this.OnPageIndexChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
                if (databind)
                    this.RequiresDataBinding = true;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnTotalRowCountAvailable(PageEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<PageEventArgs> handler = (EventHandler<PageEventArgs>)base.Events[DataPagerGridView.EventTotalRowCountAvailable];
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected override int CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding)
        {
            int rows = base.CreateChildControls(dataSource, dataBinding);

            //  if the paging feature is enabled, determine the total number of rows in the datasource
            if (this.AllowPaging)
            {
                // if we are databinding, use the number of rows that were created, 
                // otherwise cast the datasource to an Collection and use that as the count
                int totalRowCount = dataBinding ? rows : ((ICollection)dataSource).Count;

                //  raise the row count available event
                IPageableItemContainer pageableItemContainer = this as IPageableItemContainer;
                this.OnTotalRowCountAvailable(new PageEventArgs
                (pageableItemContainer.StartRowIndex, pageableItemContainer.MaximumRows, totalRowCount));

                //  make sure the top and bottom pager rows are not visible
                if (this.TopPagerRow != null)
                    this.TopPagerRow.Visible = false;

                if (this.BottomPagerRow != null)
                    this.BottomPagerRow.Visible = false;
            }
            return rows;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reorganized the code so it is correct now.

```
 public   class MyDataPagerGridView : GridView, IPageableItemContainer
    {
        private static readonly object EventTotalRowCountAvailable = new object();

        public int MaximumRows
        {
            get { return this.PageSize; }
        }

        public int StartRowIndex
        {
            get { return this.PageSize * this.PageIndex; }
        }

        public event EventHandler<PageEventArgs> TotalRowCountAvailable
        {
            add { base.Events.AddHandler(MyDataPagerGridView.EventTotalRowCountAvailable, value); }
            remove { base.Events.RemoveHandler(MyDataPagerGridView.EventTotalRowCountAvailable, value); }
        }

        public void SetPageProperties(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, bool databind)
        {
            int newPageIndex = (startRowIndex / maximumRows);
            this.PageSize = maximumRows;
            if (this.PageIndex != newPageIndex)
            {
                bool isCanceled = false;
                if (databind)
                {
                    //  create the event arguments and raise the event
                    GridViewPageEventArgs args = new GridViewPageEventArgs(newPageIndex);
                    this.OnPageIndexChanging(args);
                    isCanceled = args.Cancel;
                    newPageIndex = args.NewPageIndex;
                }
                //  if the event wasn't cancelled change the paging values
                if (!isCanceled)
                {
                    this.PageIndex = newPageIndex;
                    if (databind)
                        this.OnPageIndexChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
                if (databind)
                    this.RequiresDataBinding = true;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnTotalRowCountAvailable(PageEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<PageEventArgs> handler = (EventHandler<PageEventArgs>)base.Events[MyDataPagerGridView.EventTotalRowCountAvailable];
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected override int CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding)
        {
            int rows = base.CreateChildControls(dataSource, dataBinding);

            //  if the paging feature is enabled, determine the total number of rows in the datasource
            if (this.AllowPaging)
            {
                // if we are databinding, use the number of rows that were created, 
                // otherwise cast the datasource to an Collection and use that as the count
                int totalRowCount = dataBinding ? rows : ((ICollection)dataSource).Count;

                //  raise the row count available event
                IPageableItemContainer pageableItemContainer = this as IPageableItemContainer;
                this.OnTotalRowCountAvailable(new PageEventArgs
                (pageableItemContainer.StartRowIndex, pageableItemContainer.MaximumRows, totalRowCount));

                //  make sure the top and bottom pager rows are not visible
                if (this.TopPagerRow != null)
                    this.TopPagerRow.Visible = false;

                if (this.BottomPagerRow != null)
                    this.BottomPagerRow.Visible = false;
            }
            return rows;
        }


    }

    public partial class DataPagerGridView : UserControl
    {
        public MyDataPagerGridView DataPagerGrid = new MyDataPagerGridView();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your user control inherits the GridView class, did you intend it to inherit your DataPagerGridView class?